# How to convert an ArrayList to String array with ordered elements?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I am trying to write a method which will take an ArrayList of Student objects and return me a String array with the names of the Students in the order of their scores (student name with highest score will be at index 0).

```
public static void orderStudent(List<Student> ls) {

    for (Student stu : ls) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + stu.getName() + ", Score: "
                + stu.getScore());
    }
}
```

The above snippet when executed will print something like

```
Name: Alex, Score: 10.35
Name: Bob, Score: 11.2
Name: Charles, Score: 8.22
```

I want the orderStudent method to return a String array which would have the contents [Bob, Alex, Charles] Bob being the top scorer followed by Alex and Charles.

Comment: Which Java are you using(is it 8)?

Comment: *... return me a String array ...*

First step to that would be make the method `Student[]`, not `void`.

Comment: Ofcourse. I had posted the method as is. The return type would be changed to Student[] and the method will have a return studarray; statment at the end.

Comment: Actually the return type should be `String[]`

Comment: Thanks Jason. The method just returns the Student names in a String array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the array by a list:

```
public static List<String> orderStudent(List<Student> ls) {
    Collections.sort(ls, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return o2.getScore().compareTo(o1.getScore());
        }
    });
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Student s : ls) {
        result.add(s.getName());
    }
    return result;
}
```

If using Java 8 it would be less than two lines...

Answer (score 2):

If `Student` implements the `Comparable` interface and sorts by Score, then you simply sort the list, and build your array of names.

If you can't edit the `Student` class, you need to write a class that implements `Comparator<Student>` and use that to sort the list and then build your array of names.

Simplifying @PrasadKhode's answer:

```
public static String[] orderStudent(List<Student> list) {

    String[] students = new String[list.size()];

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student object1, Student object2) {
            return Integer.compare(object2.getScore(), object1.getScore());
        }
    });

    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        Student student = list.get(index);
        students[index] = student.getName();
        System.out.println("Name: " + student.getName());
    }

    return students;
}
```

There's no need to create an instance of a `CompareToBuilder` for each comparison for scores. That's inefficient.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But what if I dont have the access to make changes to Student class (meaning if it is from an external jar or a framework class)

Comment: So you write a class that implements `Comparator<Student>` and use that to sort the array.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to sort your List and then you need to construct String[]

You can use `CompareToBuilder` class **without making any changes to your existing POJO** class.

On CompareToBuilder you need to add the property on which you need to sort your collection. You can see the below code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.CompareToBuilder;
...

public static String[] orderStudent(List<Student> list) {

    String[] students = new String[list.size()];

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student object1, Student object2) {
            return new CompareToBuilder().append(object2.getScore(), object1.getScore()).toComparison();
        }
    });

    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        Student student = list.get(index);
        students[index] = student.getName();
        System.out.println("Name: " + student.getName());
    }

    return students;
}
```

Comment: Instantiating a CompareToBuilder each time a comparison is made is inefficient, especially given that the comparison is so simple.

Comment: @Jason is there any other way to do this without writing the comparison logic if I have to sort based on multiple fields

Comment: What would be ideal is if the `CompareToBuilder` could somehow be constructed outside the compare method, so that it doesn't get constructed for each comparison. But I don't think that is possible. It is inefficient in this instance because we are only comparing one field, so writing the actual comparison is better.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how simple it could be.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define in your Student object some to string serialization ( optional )
2. You need to sort your object with custom comporator that orders by score ( required )

   Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)

   - list is your list
   - c is comparator
3. iterate over the sorted collection and print

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement 2 things in your `Student` Class: `Comparable`, and a override to the `.toString()` method.  First, define you student class like:

`public class Student implements Comparable<Student>`

Then you must define the `.compareTo()` Method as follows:

```
//used for sorting later
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    return this.getScore().compareTo(other.getScore());//Assuming Student.score is not a primitive type
}
```

Also override the `.toString()` method as follows:

```
//used for printing later
public string toString() {
    return "Name: " + this.getName() + ", Score: " + this.getScore().toString();
}
```

Now you can simply change your `orderStudents` function to the following:

```
public static void orderStudent(List<Student> ls) {

// this will sort your collection based on the logic in the `Student.compareTo()` method.
ls = Collections.sort(ls);

for (Student stu : ls) {
//this will print the student object based on the `Student.toString()` method
        System.out.println(stu);
    }
}
```